# Windows installed from flash drive won't boot when flash drive is NOT inserted

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, mbr

I installed Win 10 from flash drive on C drive, and it works fine as long as there's flash drive inserted on boot. If there is none, the system won't load. I am POSITIVE that the system wasn't installed on the flash drive. Somebody suggested that MBR could be located on flash drive, but without any advice how to move it to hdd.

Is there a relatively easy way to fix it? I have live USB drive with Linux if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a unheard of issue.  Unfortunately, Windows 10 doesnt do a good enough job checking if the options the users picks during installation are *really* what they want.  However, this is not a hard problem to fix.  Simply google "[windows 10 boot repair](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%2010%20boot%20repair&oq=windows%2010%20boot%20r&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l7.11558j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)" and you will find countless articles on how to fix this.  This [article](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/fix-windows-10-wont-boot-startup-repair-bootrec/) is well written.  Just skip down to the section called "Fix Windows 10 Winload.exe Using the Command Prompt."